# Pop up menu in Windows Phone

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-7

How to create a pop up menu from appbar icon (like attach in whatsapp) in WP using VB/XAML. I tried it using the navigation but unable to perform it instead of navigating to another page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that attach in whatsapp is a simple grid and button from AppBar only changes its visibility. Also page OnBackKeyPress set e.Cancel = true if attach grid content is visible.

So XAML will look like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!--Header-->
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />    <!--Content-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!--Fake popup-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="2"
          x:Name="SomeName"
          Visibility="Collapsed">
        <!-- Fake popup-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Update:**

For you content of the page should look like this:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!--Header-->
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />    <!--Content-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!--Fake popup-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2"
          x:Name="SomeName"
          Visibility="Collapsed">
        <!--Popup-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="show popup"
                                        IconUri="/icon.png"
                                        Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

And page code on VB.net will look like this:

```
Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    ' If you want to hide popup when Back key pressed '    
    Protected Overrides Sub OnBackKeyPress(e As ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
        If SomeName.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible Then
            SomeName.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
            e.Cancel = True
        End If

        MyBase.OnBackKeyPress(e)
    End Sub

    ' Here is popup will appear and hide '    
    Private Sub ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If SomeName.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible Then
            SomeName.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
        Else
            SomeName.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That was helpful but another problem is to navigate in the same page. Could you help me with that please

Comment: I don't completely understand, your problem is to show popup, right? Or do you want to navigate from this page to exactly the same? Or what navigation do you talk about?

Comment: Ha yeah to show popup when click is operated but didn't got where to embed the code